# How do I clear the cache without restarting my terminal?

Tags: bash, python, cache, datascience-anaconda

I'm currently working on the POD supercomputer at UT Austin. Tech support for the supercomputer couldn't help me. There's a specific version of Python (3.9) I want to use in my Anaconda environment, but an incorrect version of Python (3.11) is cached:

[image]

I initially solved this issue by doing hash -r and then restarting my terminal (the changes don't take place unless I restart it). However, this solution doesn't work when I type "screen." The cached location for Python comes back. I can't do hash -r and then restart "screen" because it'll create a new process and the cache comes back.

Do you have a solution for clearing the hash table whenever I do "screen?"

Thanks!

Comment: are you really activating your/the correct conda environment?

Comment: `hash` is a Bash built-in command that only affects the current Bash process. Each Bash process is entirely responsible for its own hashed command cache, which is updated for every command that Bash executes for the first time. There is no way that the hash "comes back" to a fresh shell, and it is is not exported to sub-shells. `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` might be informative -- I get 3 binaries and 5 links.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I am activating the correct conda environment. I used `conda list` to double-check that it has the correct version of Python that I want, too.

Comment: but do you activate it for every shell you start? I'm asking because you say you restart your terminal, which would totally make any previous activation of the conda environment meaningless

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I do.

Answer (score 2):

`hash -r` only affects the current shell, so restarting makes rehashing moot.  Changing your path should cause your paths to be automatically rehashed.  So `hash -r` should only be necessary if you installed something new in your path without modifying the path or restarting your shell.   The cache does not "come back", it's not the cache that is the problem here.  (This is an XY problem.  Probably tech support can't help you because you are asking them to solve a problem that isn't there.)

The hash table is not what causes something to be found in your path.  The setting of `$PATH` does that.  If the wrong executable is being found, it is because it is earlier in your path than the correct one and possibly the correct one isn't in your path at all.

If you are using modules or virtual environments, then you need to unload the module or deactivate the virtual environment that is including the wrong python.  And then you need to activate the correct one or otherwise add the directory it is in to your path.

If the wrong one is still there when you restart your shell then there must be something in your shell init files (perhaps `.bashrc` assuming you are using bash) that is putting it there or the right one was never activated.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing in my .bashrc file where I set the path to include `/stor/work/<user>/anaconda/bin/python` (the path in the picture above). The only possible exception is in the conda initialization in .bashrc, where the path is set to `/stor/work/<user>/anaconda/bin`, but I assume that Conda would instead look in my environment's directory whenever I activate my environment. I do indeed activate the correct environment after creating a new process with "screen," so I'm not sure why "type python" always returns `/stor/work/<user>/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: Of course the conda initialization adds that to your path.  The venv may add another directory (hopefully) before that.  But if the venv was built from the same conda, it likely also uses the same python binary, so this might not be wrong.